# How can I set home view for forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I created a viewer which includes multiple svf.
Now I want to set camera to see every parts after viewer start.
And also I want to set camera when I click home view button to make view that we can see every parts.

[after clicking home view button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1U5L.png)

How can I set home view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by either of the following:

```js
viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsHome(false); //!<<< set current view as home

//or

viewer.autocam.setCurrentViewAsHome(true); //!<<< focus first and set current view as home
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. 
But I can't get `cam` of viewer, maybe because of the version.
Instead of your way, I found `autocam` on viewer and it has `setCurrentViewAsHome` function. I could set home view with this function.

Comment: My apologies for the typo. I missed the `auto` prefix while copying from my codes.